# data dictionary extraction in orientdb

Tags: database, graph, orientdb, data-dictionary

I have been going over the orientdb documentation to see whether I could find something that would allow for an automatic creation of data dictionaries for existing models. In other words, my use case is that every time the nodes, edges and properties are modified, the corresponding data dictionary documenting each of these would be automatically updated.

I found some sparse documentation about [VertexLabels](http://goo.gl/4uJYGb), but not sure whether this would be a way to go

any input would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case correctly, [Dynamic Hooks](http://www.orientechnologies.com/docs/last/orientdb.wiki/Dynamic-Hooks.html) (or the Java version) is what you need. When a document (i.e. Vertex of Edge) changes a trigger is fired. JavaScript or SQL scripts can be executed. So generation / updating documentation should be possible with JavaScript and mustache templates or similar technology.